# intersection multiplicity and tangeant space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $V \subset \mathbb P^n(k)$ be a projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Define $V'\subset Gr(n,n+1) \times \mathbb P^n(k)$ as the set of $(H,x)$ such that $H$ is an hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n(k)$ and $x \in H \cap V$. Is that true that if $(H,x)$ is a regular point of $V'$ for all $x \in H \cap V$, then the intersection multiplicity of $V$ and $H$ along each irreducible component is $1$?

Comment: Ok the answer is no in fact.

Comment: Let $F = h_0 x_0 + h_1 x_1 + h_2 x_2 = 0$ and $G = x_2 x_0^2 - x_1^2 = 0$ and $V = V(G) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$ and $V' = V(F,G)$. Then $H = V(h_0, h_1)$ seems to fulfill that $(H,x)$ is a regular point of $V'$ for all $x \in H \cap V$ but $H \cap V$ contains the point $x_0=1,x_1=0,x_2=0$ where the local ring is $(k[x,y]/(y-x^2,y))_{(x,y)}$ with $x=x_1/x_0$ and $y=x_2/x_0$. Do you agree with this counterexample?

Comment: Yes in fact I found the same counter-example that's why I made my first comment.